# Error "Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type "

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Hi all i have researched this problem thoroughly and i saw there were a few topics on stack about this problem but no answers. If anyone can give me a solution i would really appreciate it. Here is my code:

```
public class Deliveries extends Fragment {
    DatabaseReference dbRef;
    FirebaseDatabase myRef;
    List<customerInfo>myList;
    View delView;
    RecyclerView custCards;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        delView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_delivery_card_layout,container,false);
        custCards = (RecyclerView)delView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewResults);
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dbRef = myRef.getReference("customers123456");
        custCards.setHasFixedSize(true);
        custCards.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(delView.getContext()));

        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                myList = new ArrayList<customerInfo>();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    customerInfo val = snapshot.getValue(customerInfo.class);
                    customerInfo customerInfo = new customerInfo();

                    String nme,id,delType,km;
                    nme = val.getCustName();
                    id = val.getCustID();
                    delType = val.getDeliveryType();
                    km = val.getKmTravel();

                    customerInfo.setCustName(nme);
                    customerInfo.setCustID(id);
                    customerInfo.setDeliveryType(delType);
                    customerInfo.setKmTravel(km);

                    myList.add(customerInfo);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myList,delView.getContext());
        custCards.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        custCards.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        return delView;
    }
}
```

the data being pulled from firebase needs to populate a cardview. Here is my recycle view adapter class:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.Viewholder> {
    Context context;
    List<customerInfo> info;

    public RecyclerAdapter(List<customerInfo> temp,Context _context){
        this.context = _context;
        info = temp;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View myView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_delivery,parent,false);
        Viewholder viewholder = new Viewholder(myView);
        return viewholder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.Viewholder holder, int position) {
        customerInfo myLst = info.get(position);
        holder.cName.setText(myLst.getCustName());
        holder.cID.setText(myLst.getCustID());
        holder.cDel.setText(myLst.getDeliveryType());
        holder.cKm.setText(myLst.getKmTravel());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class Viewholder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView cName;
        public TextView cID;
        public TextView cDel;
        public TextView cKm;

        public Viewholder(View item){
            super(item);
            cName = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.txtvwCustNme);
            cID = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.txtvwCustID);
            cDel = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.txtvwDelType);
            cKm = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.txtvwEstKm);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my customers information class:

```
public class customerInfo {
    public String custName;
    public String custID;
    public String deliveryType;
    public String kmTravel;


    public String getCustID() {
        return custID;
    }

    public void setCustID(String custID) {
        this.custID = custID;
    }

    public String getKmTravel() {
        return kmTravel;
    }


    public String getCustName() {
        return custName;
    }

    public String getDeliveryType() {
        return deliveryType;
    }

    public void setCustName(String custName) {
        this.custName = custName;
    }

    public void setDeliveryType(String deliveryType) {
        this.deliveryType = deliveryType;
    }

    public void setKmTravel(String kmTravel) {
        this.kmTravel = kmTravel;
    }
}
```

Like i said before i have been trying to solve this issue by looking at previous problems that have been posted on stack but no luck. I have another class where it pulls from firebase and it works perfectly, the difference between the two classes is this:

Deliveries class (Doesnt work):

```
customerInfo val = snapshot.getValue(customerInfo.class);
```

Home class (Works):

```
myData.add(snapshot.getValue(String.class));
```

my exact error from the android monitor:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.anthe.question2, PID: 4947
                                                                           com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.anthe.question2.customerInfo
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.example.anthe.question2.Deliveries$1.onDataChange(Deliveries.java:44)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZV(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

The database structure:
[db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx98R.png)

Comment: Casting error . Debug your code .

Comment: tried debugging. It did not work.

Comment: Debugging will not work . It will makes you find the error . Check the Object type in that line number where you getting the exception.. You are casting a string to an Concrete class object .

Comment: Can you show me your Firebase data structure?

Comment: i cant embed any images because my reputation is not at 10 yet

Comment: @Lady_A give me the link, I will attach it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the structure of your code but I think `myRef.getReference("customers123456")` is already get a reference to specific user.

If you loop through all childrens using `for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())` the `snapshot` will be a attribute/element of your `customerInfo` class (Eg: custName - which represent a String)

So you should remove the loop, or get reference to parent of this "customers123456" node to get a list of your customers.

Comment: At this time there is some dummy text in the data for testing purposes, when the application is working, it should pull a multitude of data and fill a cardview automatically. I dont understand how removing my loop will fix the error because as far as i understand, i am being told by the android monitor that i cannot convert a type String to a class attribute but the class attribute is a string, all attributes are a string.

Comment: @Lady_A I know all attribute of your class is a String. Please give me your data structure, especially this node "customers123456"

Comment: okay i will try type it out - customers123456 than the children are as follow: custName1, custId1, delType1,estKm1. The customers123456 node is a child of the main node "question2-866c1"

Comment: Exactly what I think. "customers123456" is already a customer not a list of customers. So if you loop through it's childrens, you will get a list of attribute of your customer class - which represent in a String. 

So if you want to keep the loop and everything inside it: change your reference to: `myRef.getReference("question2-866c1")`

Comment: By setting reference to parent node like: `myRef.getReference("question2-866c1")`, later if you add more customer, you can use the loop to get all of these customers.

Comment: ok i see what you are saying but then how does the code for my home class work? its the same but the reference is different.

Comment: Which home class? If you want to get a list object of a class, getReference() to the parent node of the list, then loop through it's childrens to execute `snapshot.getValue(your_home_class.class);`, the parser will parse/map the data for you base on your attribute name.

Comment: okay so i made the changes and its not breaking anymore but i am still not getting any output. just a blank screen

Comment: please debug and see what is returned by snapshot.getValue()